# External leg correction to 3-point QED Green's function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, correlation-functions

I am trying to calculate the following diagram to solve the Callan-Symanzik equation for the three-point Green's function (two massless fermions and a photon).

[image]

The counterterm to the photon propagator is given as $-i(g^{\mu \nu} q^2 - q^{\mu} q^{\nu})\delta_{3}$. Hence the diagram should have the value

$$\frac{i}{\not{p}_{1}} \frac{i}{\not{p}_{2}}\Big(\frac{-ig_{\mu \nu}}{q^2}\Big)(-i e \gamma^{\sigma})\Big(\frac{-ig_{\rho \sigma}}{q^2}\Big)(-i(q^2 g^{\rho \nu} - q^{\rho} q^{\nu})\delta_{3}) $$

However, the calculation only works if I ignore the $q^{\rho} q^{\nu}$ term. I don't understand why this should be the case.